# How to set a new value for a public int in java

Tags: java, variables, integer

In the java programming language, how do you set a new value for a public integer, so that an outside method in an outside class can get this value, by simply calling the variable name. I have example code:

```
    package build;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Main main = new Main();
            main.init();
        }

        public int myVar = 1;
```

EDIT:

More specific question: How can I get the variable's updated value, not it's starting value without passing it on to a the method?

```
        public void init() {
            Retrieve ret = new Retrieve();
            int i = 0;
            for(int n = 1; n > 0; ++n) {
                myVar = myVar + 1;
                System.out.println("Value: " + myVar);
                i = ret.init();
                System.out.println("Retrieved Value: " + i);
            }
        }

        int getValue()  {
            int b = myVar;
            return b;
        }
    }
```

and for Return:

```
    package build;

    public class Retrieve {

        public int init() {
            Main main = new Main();
            int a = 1;
            a = main.getValue();
            return a;
        }
    }
```

In the example above, how would I set the variable "myVar" to a value other than one, so that when I call the 'init' method in the 'return' class, it returns that new value, rather than 1, the starting value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something very wrong with your object relationship.

The main problem is in Retrieve.init()

```
public int init() {
        Main main = new Main();
        int a = 1;
        a = main.getValue();
```

Every time you call init() you are making a new instance of main, so main.myVar will be 1.  I assume you wanted to call the value of the first main.

```
public class Retrieve {

    public int init(Main main) {            
        int a = 1;
        a = main.getValue();
        return a;
    }
}
```

and in Main.init change

```
Retrieve ret = new Retrieve();
```

to

```
Retrieve ret = new Retrieve(this);
```

Comment: Oh that makes sense, I'll try that and get back to you.

Comment: Worked wonderfully, except that Instead of setting "Retrieve ret = new Retrieve(this)" I set "i = ret.init(this)" Other than that perfect answer, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly awful [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), but this *will* work:

```
public class Retrieve {

    public int init() {
        Main main = new Main();
        int a = 1;
        main.myVar = 42;
        a = main.getValue();
        return a; // returns 42
    }
}
```

Comment: will it work if instead of saying (in my main class) main.myVar = main.myVar + 1? Thats what I'm trying to do, is retrieve the variable, without setting it to the value needed, I want to be able to retrieve it and get it's updated value, not it's starting value.